# Get AUTO_INCREMENT *before* database insertion in MySQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-insert, auto-increment

I'm developing a MySQL database project using JDBC. It uses parent/child tables linked with foreign keys.

TL;DR: I want to be able to get the `AUTO_INCREMENT` id of a table *before* an `INSERT` statement. I am already aware of the `getGeneratedKeys()` method in JDBC to do this following an insert, but my application requires the ID before insertion. Maybe there's a better solution to the problem for this particular application? Details below:

---

In a part of this application, the user can create a new item via a form or console input to enter details - some of these details are in the form of "sub-items" within the new item.

These inputs are stored in Java objects so that each row of the table corresponds to one of these objects - here are some examples:

```
MainItem
 - id (int)
 - a bunch of other details...

MainItemTitle 
 - mainItemId (int)
 - languageId (int)
 - title (String)

ItemReference
 - itemId (int) <-- this references MainItem id
 - referenceId (int) <-- this references another MainItem id that is linked to the first
```

So essentially each Java object represents a row in the relevant table of the MySQL database.

When I store the values from the input into the objects, I use a dummy id like so:

```java
private static final int DUMMY_ID = 0;

...

MainItem item = new MainItem(DUMMY_ID, ...);

// I read each of the titles and initialise them using the same dummy id - e.g.
MainItemTitle title = new MainItemTitle(DUMMY_ID, 2, "Here is a a title");

// I am having trouble with initialising ItemReference so I will explain this later
```

Once the user inputs are read, they are stored in a "holder" class:

```java
class MainItemValuesHolder {

    MainItem item;
    ArrayList<MainItemTitle> titles;
    ArrayList<ItemReference> references;
    // These get initialised and have getters and setters, omitted here for brevity's sake
}

...

MainItemValuesHolder values = new MainItemValuesHolder();
values.setMainItem(mainItem);
values.addTitle(englishTitle);
values.addTitle(germanTitle);
// etc...
```

In the final layer of the application (in another class where the values holder was passed as an argument), the data from the "holder" class is read and inserted into the database:

```java
// First insert the main item, belonging to the parent table

MainItem mainItem = values.getMainItem();
String insertStatement = mainItem.asInsertStatement(true); // true, ignore IDs
// this is an oversimplification of what actually happens, but basically constructs the SQL statement while *ignoring the ID*, because...

int actualId = DbConnection.insert(insertStatement);
// updates the database and returns the AUTO_INCREMENT id using the JDBC getGeneratedKeys() method

// Then do inserts on sub-items belonging to child tables
ArrayList<MainItemTitle> titles = values.getTitles();
for (MainItemTitle dummyTitle : titles) {
    MainItemTitle actualTitle = dummyTitle.replaceForeignKey(actualId);
    String insertStatement = actualTitle.asInsertStatement(false); // false, use the IDs in the object
    DbConnection.insert(insertStatement);
}
```

Now, the issue is using this procedure for `ItemReference`. Because it links two `MainItem`s, using the (or multiple) dummy IDs to construct the objects beforehand destroys these relationships.

The most obvious solution seems to be being able to get the `AUTO_INCREMENT` ID beforehand so that I don't need to use dummy IDs.

I suppose the other solution is inserting the data as soon as it is input, but I would prefer to keep different functions of the application in separate classes - so one class is responsible for one action. Moreover, by inserting as soon as data is input, then if the user chooses to cancel before completing entering all data for the "main item", titles, references, etc., the now invalid data would need to be deleted.

---

**In conclusion, how would I be able to get `AUTO_INCREMENT` *before* insertion? Is there a better solution for this particular application?**

Comment: *"Is there a better solution for this particular application?"* Re-design the implementation so you don't need the ID before INSERT, e.g. insert the `MainItem` objects first and update the object with the newly assigned ID, *then* insert the `ItemReference` objects. Seems self-evident to me.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the comment - I'll try redesigning the implementation and how `ItemReference`s are handled.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the value before the insert. You cannot know what other actions may be taken on the table. AUTO_INCREMENT may not be incrementing by one, you may have set that but it could be changed.

You *could* use a temporary table to store the data with keys under your control.  I would suggest using a Uuid rather than an Id so you can assume it will always be unique.  Then your other classes can copy data into the live tables, you can still link the data using the Uuids to find related data in your temporary table(s), but write it in the order that makes sense to the database (so the 'root' record first to get it's key and then use that where required.

Comment: I haven't looked into UUIDs much yet (this is the first proper database project I'm working on), but from what I understand they're unique across the whole database. But surely in both cases I would insert data into the tables in the same way, linked with foreign keys (or UUIDs), and with the data of the parent table being inserted first, followed by that of the child tables. What's the difference between using integer primary keys vs UUIDs?

Comment: Only that if you use IDs you have to track them to know what you can assign which will bring you back to the problem you started with.  If you use a uuid you can just make one when you need one (you will have to know what it is to find it again, but you have already provided for that in your logic if it was an AUTO_INCREMENT)

Comment: Changing your main tables to use Uuids is likely going to be a big task.  But for the specific case of temporary tables here you could use them nd I think it would make your life easier.